# Need info on asymptotes

Tags: calculus, reference-request

Can anyone suggest me video lectures on asymptotes? Not able to understand how to calculate asymptotes - my book says put $x = 1, y =m$, then $\phi_n(m) = 0$, some formula to find $c$, some Taylor-like formula to find $c$ when $\phi$ goes to zero. where $\phi (m)$ is highest degree terms in curve $f(x,y)=0$

How the following holds?
if $y = mx+c$ is asymptote, then $m = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac {y}{x}, c = \lim_{x \to \infty} y-mx $

there is another expression for c,$c = \frac {- \phi_{n-1}(x)}{\phi^{'}_{n}(x)}$

again some expression in case of denominator in above equation zero ....

Comment: Your post is incomprehensible: you must tell us what $y$, $\phi_n$ are, etc.

Comment: I don't know about video lectures, but a lot of older books have extensive treatments of asymptotes, such as [**A First Course in the Differential and Integral Calculus**](https://archive.org/details/firstcourseindif00ford) by Walter Burton Ford (see Chapter XII on pp. 128-142), [**An Elementary Treatise on the Differential Calculus**](https://archive.org/details/anelementarytre01edwagoog) by Joseph Edwards (see Chapter VIII on pp. 182-210), [**A Treatise on the Differential Calculus**](https://archive.org/details/atreatiseondiff04todhgoog) by Isaac Todhunter (see Chapter XIX on pp. 290-303).

Comment: thnx for info. will go thru them.

Comment: See also Jovan D. Kečkić, [*A method for obtaining asymptotes of some curves*](http://www.teaching.math.rs/vol/tm314.pdf), **The Teaching of Mathematics** (Mathematical Society of Serbia) 3 #1 (2000), 53-59 AND Haghdad S. Memauri and Herman Lee Windham, [*On asymptotes of the graphs of algebraic functions*](http://pentagon.kappamuepsilon.org/pentagon/Vol_52_Num_2_Spring_1993.pdf), **The Pentagon** 52 #2 (Spring 1993), 39-50. I think the Memauri/Windham paper will probably be the most suitable for you.